# C# Web API not working on simple MVC5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to get a simple example working for Web API and MVC5 but so far, it's not working. I created a simple MVC5 application on Visual Studio 2013 that shows a table contents. I'd like to add Web API to this. I've added a Web API controller which seems to have added all the necessary dependencies. However, when I run the Web API part, I get a 404. I'm pretty sure the issue is with one of the following files.

Global.aspx:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MountJoy", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Auto-generated Controller:

```
public class RemoteController : ApiController
{
    private MountJoyDBEntities db = new MountJoyDBEntities();

    // GET api/Remote
    public IQueryable<Inmate> GetInmates()
    {
        return db.Inmates;
    }

    // GET api/Remote/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Inmate))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInmate(int id)
    {
        Inmate inmate = db.Inmates.Find(id);
        if (inmate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(inmate);
    }

    // PUT api/Remote/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutInmate(int id, Inmate inmate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != inmate.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(inmate).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!InmateExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/Remote
    [ResponseType(typeof(Inmate))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostInmate(Inmate inmate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Inmates.Add(inmate);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = inmate.Id }, inmate);
    }

    // DELETE api/Remote/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Inmate))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteInmate(int id)
    {
        Inmate inmate = db.Inmates.Find(id);
        if (inmate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Inmates.Remove(inmate);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(inmate);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool InmateExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Inmates.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the controller code as well.

Comment: How are you testing if it is working or nor?

Comment: From @erfan: Does this controller exist at all? MountJoy?

Comment: What URL are you using to try to perform the GET request? If you set a break point in your action method, is it reached?

Comment: What error are you getting?